# Two versions of Windows 10 listed under "Reset This PC". How to delete one of them?

Tags: windows-10, reset

I recently "Reset" my copy of Windows 10 by selecting the option "Keep My Files".

However, now the Recovery Environment lists two copies of Windows 10 under the "Reset This PC" option.

Both copies are on **Volume 3** of the Diskpart utility (accessible from CMD prompt by typing Diskpart).

How can I cleanly and safely remove one of these copies without risking the files and programs associated with the "Keep my Files and Folders" option that I selected above? Also, ideas as to what caused this error would be helpful.

Comment: Have you removed the Windows.old directory?

Comment: The "Reset This PC - Keep Files" option doesn't seem to have done anything. Now that I've restarted the PC it's still the same OS as before the reset, no reset is apparent. ALSO when the PC starts Windows asks me to select an OS but only lists one OS. This is the old-school black screen with a "Select Operating System" prompt (that also features the Windows Memory Diagnostics option).

Comment: Your question does not reflect the fact your machine failed to perform the Reset.

Comment: It is important to understand that "Reset This PC", results in a **new** installation of Windows, only after the installation is successful is your personal files within your user's profile directory migrated to the new installation.  The fact you are being prompted to select which installation you want to use, means the processed failed.  You can prevent that by modifying the BCD, getting rid of the incorrect/invalid entry, and then configuring a default selection.